# ¿Cómo hacer que una cookie expire a medianoche del día en que se creó?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Estoy intentando guardar una cookie en la que se guardan los datos del usuario que ingresa.

Solamente quiero que estén ahí esos datos por solamente ese día, por lo tanto a las **00:00** debería borrarse.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acuerdo con [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683759/1983854) en [Code Javascript for a cookie that expires at midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20683394/1983854), se trataría de hacer algo así:

```
var medianoche = new Date();
medianoche.setHours(23,59,59,0);

$.cookie('anewsletter', '1', { expires: medianoche });
```

Es decir, creas la [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) y le pasas el parámetro `expires` con la fecha y hora en que quieres que expire. Esta fecha la generas dinámicamente con el objeto `Date` y le asignas la hora a las 23:59:59.

Ojo: la documentación indica que la hora la lee en GMT, así que si estás en otro huso horario ajústala según te convenga.

Comment: Oh, muchas gracias, lo revisaré

Comment: Pregunta ¿Hay forma de comprobar sí está así en la cookie?

Comment: @DaxTter77 abre la consola y mira sus propiedades.

Comment: Te comento, lo hice y la cuestión es que dice que expira a las 18:59:59

Comment: Mira la documentación que enlacé, pues ahí indica _expires=date-in-GMTString-format_. Debes pues ajustarla al huso horario que desees

Comment: Ah, vale, gracias, ya lo reviso

Answer (score 0):

Fijar el tiempo de expiración de una cookie se hace fijando una fecha mediante el campo expire de la siguiente manera:

```
res.cookie(name , 'value', {expire : new Date() + 9999});
```

Comment: `new Date() + 9999 = "Mon Oct 07 2019 15:50:04 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)9999"`. No es la manera correcta